# How merge multi file audio record in android?

Tags: android

I had try merge by code, but it only has data of first file.

```
  if (dsFile.size() > 1) {
            byte[] fileContent = null;
            byte[] fileContenttotal = null;
            FileInputStream ins;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                createFilename();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mFileName, true);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            int maxlength = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dsFile.size(); i++) {
                File f = new File(dsFile.get(i));
                maxlength += f.length();
            }
            fileContenttotal = new byte[maxlength];
            int tagetidx = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < dsFile.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    File f = new File(dsFile.get(i));
                    Log.v("TAG", "File Length:" + f.length());
                    fileContent = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                    ins = new FileInputStream(dsFile.get(i));
                    int r = ins.read(fileContent);

                    for (int j = 0; j < fileContent.length; j++) {

                        fileContenttotal[tagetidx++] = fileContent[j];
                    }

                    // }
                    // f.delete();
                    Log.v("TAG", "File" + i + "is Appended");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            try {
                fos.write(fileContenttotal);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.close();
                Log.v("Record Message", "===== Combine File Closed =====");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

How merge multi file audio record in android?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: MovieCreator.build(..) only accept String or DataSource. Not accept Channels.newChannel(fstream). But i set  MovieCreator.build(..) to filename, if show error at IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(audio1);

Comment: Can you send to me your file libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are recording audio file then we are also provide resume/pause functionality.Then we can save different file and then after merge them. We can use following method to merge file.If we want to delete all files after merge then can pass on more parameter deltemp flag variable true/false.

```
public void combine(boolean deltemp)
{
try
{
List<Track> audioTraks=new ArrayList<Track>();
FileInputStream fstream1=new           FileInputStream(getFilenameFromTemp(0));

if(resume_counter==0)
{

Movie audios;

FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream(getFilenameFromTemp(0));
audios=MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(fstream));
audioTraks.add((Track)audios.getTracks().get(0));

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Movie audio1 = MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(fstream1));
audio1.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());

Track[] tracks = new Track[1];
tracks[0] = audioTraks.get(0);
audio1.addTrack(new AppendTrack(tracks));

IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(audio1);

String outPutFileName=getFilename();
Log.d("Output file Name","Output==>"+outPutFileName);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilename()));
out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
fos.close();
if(deltemp)
{
if(deleteFileFromSD(getFilenameFromTemp(0)))
{
}
}

}
else
{
Movie audios;
for(int i=0;i<resume_counter;i++)
{
FileInputStream fstream=new  FileInputStream(getFilenameFromTemp(i));
audios=MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(fstream));
audioTraks.add((Track)audios.getTracks().get(0));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Movie audio1 = MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(fstream1));
audio1.setTracks(new LinkedList<Track>());

Track[] tracks = new Track[resume_counter];
for(int i=0;i<resume_counter;i++)
{
tracks[i] = audioTraks.get(i);
}
audio1.addTrack(new AppendTrack(tracks));

IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(audio1);

String outPutFileName=getFilename();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilename()));
out.getBox(fos.getChannel());
fos.close();

if(deltemp)
{
for(int j=0;j<resume_counter;j++)
{
deleteFileFromSD(getFilenameFromTemp(j));
}
}
}
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

In the above code getFileFromTemp() is function tp get file from temp folder if created.Other wise call the same folder.

I hope this will help.Thanks!!

Comment: I code: ins = new FileInputStream(dsFile.get(0)); Movie audio1 = MovieCreator.build(Channels.newChannel(ins)); It show error: The method build(String) in the type MovieCreator is not applicable for the arguments (ReadableByteChannel). error at: MovieCreator.build

Comment: Please check the imported package as well put the library.

Comment: i had import file isoviewer-1.0-RC-28.jar in libs of package

Comment: This code is working fine,But i have not code now .I will send you library name with complete code later on.Please remove all the imported package on top of class then import again.try good luck.

Comment: Can you send to me your file libs?

Comment: Yes,Please download the library by following following link. http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/downloads/detail?name=isoviewer-2.0-RC-23.jar&can=2&q=label%3AType-Executable

Comment: hi. I have the same problem and very searched the web! I Used your code But Class "Track" not defined in my IDE. Should I download the above link and put it to my priject? this link not working!

Comment: This library may be removed from this location.You can download from another location.

Comment: try this http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/downloads/list?q=label:Type-Executable

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the value for the `resume_counter`  variable?

Comment: @bhaveshkaila, resume counter is a variable to count how many times you resume the recording. if you didn't resume then counter will be 0 otherwise increament it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/wiki/AppendTracks)

it's open source that you can merge video or audio in java.
I use this jar to merge video and audio successfully.

Comment: file isoviewer-1.0-RC-28.jar ?

Comment: Yes, add isoviewer-1.0-RC-28.jar to your libs folder

Comment: I code:  ins = new FileInputStream(dsFile.get(0));
 Movie audio1 = mc.build(Channels.newChannel(ins)); It show error: The method build(String) in the type MovieCreator is not applicable for the arguments (ReadableByteChannel). error at: mc.build

Comment: i am getting same error.have you found solution to this.